# Xamarin Forms App with F# in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, f#

Is there a template for one of these in Visual Studio? I can't find one installed or online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. There is one for Xamarin Studio, but it will not work in Visual Studio.

You can create a C# "Xamarin.Forms Portable" solution, which will create the platform-specific applications in C#, and then replace the shared C# PCL with an F# PCL to do the cross-platform development. You just need to`Install-Package Xamarin.Forms` to the F# PCL and it should work. (You can also create and reference F# PCLs for the platform-specific code if you so desire.)